# NodeJS Server requests per second

Tags: node.js, request

I am running a redirect server in Node.JS. The server accepts requests in the form /?url=http://google.com and redirects the client to that page. We have been load testing the server and only getting 18k requests per second. Is there a way to increase this throughput?

Comment: How about this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195177/what-is-the-performance-for-node-js-http-request-how-many-concurrent-request?rq=1?

Comment: We had already opened up the ulimit value on both the load testing clients and the servers

Comment: Hi Alex, this is a late reply but I wanted to know if you did some specific configurations to get the 18k /sec. How many processes did you use? Thanks, Paul